# Suppose a theta graph's three cycles are all unknots. Must it be unknotted?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, knot-theory

Here's small knot theory question involving a knotted graph.

A theta graph is a $\theta$ shape: two vertices with three parallel edges between them. It has three cycles, each obtained by deleting an edge.

Say we embed a theta graph in $\Bbb R^3$. If each of the three cycles are unknots, is the theta graph then ambiently isotopic to a standard theta graph?

My intuition says yes, but I don't know where to start for proving this. One idea is to fill in each unknot with an embedded disc, but I don't know how to show that this can be done such that the discs don't intersect each other or the other edge. (If they don't intersect each other, we've essentially built a sphere, and we're done.)

Comment: I mean "parallel edges" in this sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_edges

Comment: Spitballing, is there a way to glue the borromean rings into a theta?

Comment: I think not, imagine doing a braid with the theta graph in $\mathbb R^3$, i think every cycle  would be unknotted but it wouldn't  be isotopic to a standard theta graph

Comment: @MatíasUres But you can undo each crossing of the braid by "twisting" around the vertex, basically using the move described in [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1W2A.jpg)

Comment: I think I have a potential counterexample: https://i.imgur.com/T3M4erO.jpg You can see on the right that each of the three cycles is an unknot. The hard part is showing that this isn't isotopic to a standard theta; I don't know how I would prove that (and I don't have anything lying around that I can make a physical model out of)

Comment: Re: my last image: I'm pretty sure that's the same as this: https://i.imgur.com/78JZKAa.jpg. Note that, in this form, one of the cycles is a geometric circle. (I double-checked that deleting any edge yields an unknot.)

Comment: The picture you drew is the "Kinoshita graph" and is the standard counterexample. (See https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05474v2)

Comment: @LDL Whoa! Well done me for independently finding that, then! If you make this an answer rather than a comment I will gladly accept it.

Comment: It took me a moment to verify that it is, indeed, the same graph (pull in the long skinny bits of their picture)